# How to manually get a light version of a color?

Tags: android

I have a set of 20 colors with light and dark mode versions, which I can access normally depending on the theme. But I need to, in some cases, programmatically get both the light and dark variant of the color as two separate variables irrespective of the app daynight mode. Is there a way to force which version of the color is resolved using the id?

My first thought was to pass in a fake resources with a forced daynight mode, something like this:

```
val resourceLight = //Light resource/context
val resourceDark = //Light resource/context

val colorLight = ContextCompat.getColor(resourceLight,R.color.chatTextColorTeal)
val colorDark = ContextCompat.getColor(resourceDark,R.color.chatTextColorTeal)
```

But I cannot find any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using XML or Compose, so I will try to write an answer for both:

XML:

Fairly sure you can fetch a color from the selected mode (and color scheme) by using a [context wrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper#public-constructors)

```kotlin
val darkThemeContextWrapper = ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.yourDarkTheme)
val darkColor = ContextCompat.getColor(darkThemeWrapper, R.id.yourColor)
```

Compose:

you should be able to manually reference the opposite color pallete ('cause it's pretty much a global variable) or you may want to consider using [contentcolorFor](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#extension-functions-summary) to get a color that ensures sufficient contrast